# calling batch script from a batch script without pausing the execution of parent script

Tags: batch-file

I want to call a batch2 script from a batch1 script in special case , but dont want  wait parent batch1 script to wait for completion of batch2.
Want batch1 to move to next command while batch2 run in Parallel.

Answer (score 2):

The NT shell command START will pass the batch file to its own Window for execution and immediately proceed to the next line.

```
    start 1.bat
    start 2.bat
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `start` like this

```
echo batch1 command
start batch2.bat
echo batch1 carries on whilst batch2 runs at the same time
```

Answer (score 0):

Start command starts the 2nd batch file in the other window and both runs in parallel

```
@echo off
::This is the second batch file that runs in parallel with this file
start batch_file.bat
```